# How do I fix my random number generator in batch?

Tags: batch-file, random, numbers

So I am trying to code the card game of BlackJack using Batch code, and I have coded a random number generator to generate the player's cards. When I try and use the random number generator it keeps on giving the same first card and then a random second card. Here is my code to generate the player's first card:

```
    set /a val1=2
    set /a val2=14
    :FirstCard
    call :findrannumA
    echo Your first card is %rannumA%
    pause >nul
    goto Second Card

    :findrannumA
    set /a dif= ( %val2% - %val1% ) + 1
    set /a Div=32767 / %dif%
    set /a rannumA=%random% / %div%
    set /a rannumA=%rannumA% + %val1%
    if %rannumA% gtr %val2% goto findrannumA
    if %rannumA% lss %val1% goto findrannumA
    goto :EOF
```

%rannumA% is the random number, which is the number that goes with the card. (11, 12, 13, and 14 are Jack, Queen, King, and Ace.) For whatever reason, it doesn't just repeat the same answer over again. Instead, it gives one particular number between the specified limits, 2 and 14, over and over again every time you open the file, then it will change the number after a while and give another number for a while, and it keeps repeating this cycle.

Anyone know anything to help me in this situation?

Comment: Unable to recreate.  I ran this script 25 times and only got a single repeated card for two consecutive draws.  FWIW, you can shorten your entire `:findrannumA` function to just `set /a rannumA = %random% * (val2 - val1 + 1) / 32767 + val1` then `goto :EOF`.

Comment: And it doesn't on my computer either.

Comment: Or you could use a single random card function for every card.  `:randcard` then `set /a %~1 = %random% * 13 / 32767 + 2` then `goto :EOF`.  Call it like `call :randcard card1` and `call :randcard card2` to set `%card1%` and `%card2%` to random cards using the same function -- as well as hit cards, double-down, split, whatever.  One function to rule them all.

Comment: Try using delayed expansion and using `!random!` instead of `%random%`

Comment: You could generate the entire deck, if the card already exists you could re-roll that card. And then deal.